# What are expressions in mathematics?

Tags: definition, formal-languages

Like algebraic expressions are logarithmic, Experimental, trigonometric, differential, etc., expressions also there?

I am not referring to functions, but just expressions or equations. Are their definitions similar to how we define their corresponding function?

I know Functions are more frequently and widely used than any expression, why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics)

Comment: In my mind, the word "expression" does not have a precise meaning, and if I'm developing math rigorously I would avoid using the word "expression" entirely. (Maybe in some other areas of math like logic the word "expression" is given a precise meaning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [*expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics)) is essentially a string of symbols (*e.g.*, $$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ or $x^2$) [with some technical requirements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054680/what-are-expressions-in-mathematics/3054681?noredirect=1#comment6297674_3054681); an *equation* is a relationship between expressions that is given by an equality (*e.g.*, $c=2\pi r$).

---

I doubt that functions are more frequently/widely used than expressions. In mathematical literature, a typical author talks about the LHS or the RHS of the definition of a function (and the derivations thereof) far more often than the function itself. For every equation, there is at least two expressions.

Comment: Aren't Expressions classified on bases of their corresponding functions, like logarithmic expression, trigonometric expression, etc

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Then what logx called without equating it to y, and sinx, tanx ,logx should all be then same category expression inspite their corresponding function are different

Comment: Well, yeah; you're right. In those cases they are expressions involving those functions.

Comment: More than just "a string of symbols", an expression has to be a syntactically correct well-formed formula (in some formal language that's usually typical math notation).

Comment: Yes, I suppose the use of mathematical logic and formal languages is more appropriate to nail down the definition here, @JohnForkosh; you're absolutely right. I'll provide a link to your comment in this answer.

Comment: Oh, and thank you :)